# Devexpress Winforms tileview substring text forecolor

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Is it possible to change the forecolor of substring in element text in GridControls's Tileview in devexpress winforms?

What's going to happen is I have a textbox and tileview
In event while textbox textchanged fire, the text matched in tileview's element text will be highlighted

The initial color of tileview's text will be blue and if its match with textbox's text it will be highlighted as gray.

See picture to check the illustration:

Is it possible? or will i need another component to attain this output?

[image]

Comment: My advice is to use [DevExpress support tools](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/).  They are very responsive and helpful.  I have had 100% of my questions answered there, and I've never found an answer more easily here.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see there is property group called Appearance (TileView.Appearance) and there you have property called ForeColor. Moreover, you can acces via code by calling

`titleViewName.Appearance.ForeColor = <RGB value goes here>`

Finally, there is possibility for dynamic customization via event *ItemCustomize*.

For further information please check [official documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114712/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/View-Technology/Tile-View/Tutorial-Tile-View-Service-Columns-and-Dynamic-Tile-Customization) and DevExpress forum. There already existis questions similiar to yours.

Comment: Thank you for commenting 
Yes im aware of that properties and event. 
However I'm not sure if I could change the specific substring of certain text. 

Can you provide me that existing question? I did some research and tried to ask them but i couldn't find one Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use HTML Text formating for displayed string:
`Text = "This is some <color=red>red or <color=black><b>bold</b> text!"`